# How to show a loader for 3 sec and hide in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I want a loader show for 5 sec and hide when i click on a button,
so far i tried

```
<div *ngIf='showloader'  class="form-group loaderformgroup maindivdisplaynone" id="waitresponce" >
    <div class="waitresponce">
         <img src="assets/img/loader.gif" img-from="assets" alt="loader" class="waitresponceloader"/>
    </div>
</div>


 resetform() {
        this.student = {};
          Observable.timer(500).subscribe(() => {
                        $('#tablebody').addClass('fadding');
                        this.showloader = true;
                        Observable.timer(500).subscribe(() =>  
                        $('#tablebody').removeClass('fadding'); 
                        this.showloader = false 
                        );   
                        });
    }
```

my ts,

```
       setInterval(() => {  
  this.showloader = true;
}, 2000);
```

But it is showing loader after 2000.Can someone please help.Thanks.

Comment: You should use timeout instead of interval.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using `setTimeout` is not advisable with angular 2. you can use `Observable` and `timer` for it :

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/timer';

@Component({
  selector   : 'my-component'
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  public showloader: boolean = false;      
  private subscription: Subscription;
  private timer: Observable<any>;

  public ngOnInit() {
    // call this setTimer method when you want to set timer
    this.setTimer();
  }
  public ngOnDestroy() {
    if ( this.subscription && this.subscription instanceof Subscription) {
      this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  }

  public setTimer(){

    // set showloader to true to show loading div on view
    this.showloader   = true;

    this.timer        = Observable.timer(5000); // 5000 millisecond means 5 seconds
    this.subscription = this.timer.subscribe(() => {
        // set showloader to false to hide loading div from view after 5 seconds
        this.showloader = false;
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: Hi rana,in your code i want to removeclass in this but it shows type error,can you see it

Comment: this.subscription = this.timer.subscribe(() => {
        this.showloader = false;$('#tablebody').addClass('fade');
    });

Comment: you can try to use `ngClass` like `[ngClass]="{'fade': !showloader}"` as html attribute in view

Comment: so i should keep ngclass in the div where i want to use fadding?

Comment: In angular 6, instead of: 
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/timer'; 
please use : import { Subscription, Observable, timer } from 'rxjs';   And   instead of : this.timer        = Observable.timer(5000); pls use :  this.timer = timer(5000); // 5000 millisecond means 5 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show the loader for 5 sec and hide it, you should set the condition in ng-if to false in setTimeout. Right now you are doing the other way i.e setting to true after 2 sec interval. Thats why it is showing after 2 sec.

Answer (score 0):

2000 is 2 sec. try 5000
and instead of setInterval use setTimeout, it will happen only once

Comment: Hi vakho,I put in this way,its not wrkng,
       setTimeout(() => {  
  this.showloader = true;
}, 5000);

Comment: try like this: `var self=this; setTimeout(() => { self.showloader = true; }, 5000);`

Comment: this.showloader = true;  will show that loader, this.showloader = false will hide; so at start showloader = true; and by timer make it  false