# Use RxJS to start spinner, show it for at least 500ms, then stop it at most after 10s

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an RxJS `Subject<boolean>` that I use to control whether a spinner should be started (true) or stopped (false).

I'm trying to implement the following behavior in RxJS:

- When I start the spinner, I want it to **run for at least 500ms** even if stop events are received before that. In RxJS terms: when I emit a value of `true` on my Subject, a timer should start for 500ms and all values of `false` emitted on the Subject should be ignored until the timer has expired.
- I want the spinner to **stop automatically after 10,000 ms** even if no stop event has been received. In RxJS terms: when I emit a value of `true` on my Subject, another timer should start for 10000ms and a value of `false` should be emitted when this timer expires.

I am struggling to implement this. I am not sure whether I need multiple observables/subjects and which operators I should use (`delayWhen`, `takeUntil`...)

This is my spinner service so far:

```js
export class SpinnerService {
  private isVisibleSubj$ = new Subject<boolean>();
  isVisible$ = this.isVisibleSubj$.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  start() {
    this.isVisibleSubj$.next(true);
  }

  stop() {
    this.isVisibleSubj$.next(false);
  }
}
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40503667/how-to-show-a-loader-for-3-sec-and-hide-in-angular-2) help you?

Comment: Thanks. This covers the "timeout" part with the `timer` operator, but not the "run at least for n milliseconds" part.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach:

```js
let shouldSkipFalsy = false;

merge(
  of(true), // Start spinner
  of(false), // Ignored
  of(false), // Ignored
  of(false), // Ignored
  timer(400).pipe(mapTo(false)), // Ignored
  timer(10000).pipe(mapTo(false)), // Automatically stop after 10 seconds
)
  .pipe(
    exhaustMap(
      v => {
        if (v && !shouldSkipFalsy) {
          shouldSkipFalsy = true;

          /**
           * Spinner in action
           * Also ignore any falsy values for 500ms
           */
          return timer(500).pipe(mapTo(null), startWith(v), tap(() => shouldSkipFalsy = false))
        }

        return of(v);
      }
    ),
    filter(v => v !== null),
  )
  .subscribe(console.log)
```

With the help of [`exhaustMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/exhaustmap.html), which is kind of the opposite of [`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html), I managed to ignore any falsy values for a certain amount of time.
What would this do is to ignore any subsequent emitted values **until** the current **inner subscription** has **completed**.

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-timers?file=index.ts).

Comment: Thanks Andrei. I'll look into it.